# Getting sound clip position is extremely slow on Raspberry Pi

Tags: java, audio, raspberry-pi, javasound

I'm running Java 21 on a Raspberry Pi 3B (64-bit OS). Calling `javax.sound.sampled.Clip#getFramePosition()` on a running audio clip takes up to 3 seconds per call, whereas it takes less than a millisecond on my PC.

I've come back to this [over the years](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53189006/java-audio-clipgetframeposition-very-slow-on-raspberry-pi), trying:

- Different JDKs (8, 17, 21)
- Different Raspberry Pis
- Different Pi operating systems (32 and 64 bit)
- Different audio formats (my actual use case uses MP3 files, but WAV makes for a simpler reproduction case)
- An external sound card
- Running the loop on a separate thread

But I've never been able to get sensible performance out of this call. Monitoring with `top` while the code runs shows that the `java` process never consumes more than 2% of CPU or 5% of RAM.

Avenues I've considered for a solution:

- Am I missing something obvious?
- Can the audio config (or audio driver) be changed?
- Is there another way to get the progress of a Clip? I don't think `SourceDataLine` is a good fit for my use case.
- Can I raise a bug report somewhere? (Not sure whose jurisdiction this would fall under: the JDK, the Pi team, or someone else).
- How can I figure out where the performance bottleneck is?

Here's a reproducible example (requires an external `test.wav` file in the working directory):

```java
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.util.Date;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioFormat;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioInputStream;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem;
import javax.sound.sampled.Clip;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        byte[] fileBytes = Files.readAllBytes(new File("./test.wav").toPath());
        InputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(fileBytes);
        AudioInputStream ais = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(bais);

        Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
        clip.open(ais);
        clip.start();

        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            long start = new Date().getTime();
            long pos = clip.getFramePosition();
            long duration = new Date().getTime() - start;
            System.out.println("Pos: " + pos + ", duration: " + duration);
            Thread.sleep(10);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is some sample output:

```
Pos: 0, duration: 0
Pos: 32778, duration: 645
Pos: 164690, duration: 2980
Pos: 262573, duration: 2207
Pos: 426196, duration: 3698
Pos: 458820, duration: 728
Pos: 524493, duration: 1479
Pos: 557127, duration: 729
Pos: 590678, duration: 749
Pos: 656352, duration: 1478
Pos: 721684, duration: 1469
Pos: 754290, duration: 728
Pos: 786924, duration: 729
Pos: 813348, duration: 588
```

Comment: Having done crude performance testing on raspberry PI, I've found the performance to be unpredictable compared to other more 'industrial' SBCs (nvidia/udoo/fitlet). You may find far more helpful answers than mine from a more hardware-oriented forum :)

Comment: I "worked around" the issue years ago by buying an old Mac Mini and ditching the Pi, but I'd like to be able to support RPi as a low-cost option for users. This audio issue is pretty much the one blocker, unfortunately!

Comment: There is also `getMicrosecondPosition` and `getLongFramePosition`.

Comment: Thanks @greg-449, those methods both call down to `getFramePosition()` so they have the same issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple ideas. For one, I'm curious how [AudioCue-maven](https://github.com/philfrei/AudioCue-maven#readme) might work on the Raspberry PI. It operates like a `Clip` but is based upon a `SourceDataLine` and might have the best aspects of each for your use case.

Another idea, with `SourceDataLine`, you can count frames as they elapse. There's a code example in the [audio tutorials](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/sound/converters.html), in the section "Reading Audio Files" where the number of frames being read is held. With a little modification you could make the variable readable by other threads, e.g., designate it as *volatile*.

It might be helpful to experiment with different buffer settings when you [`open`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/sound/sampled/Clip.html#open(javax.sound.sampled.AudioFormat,byte%5B%5D,int,int)) the `Clip`. I'm curious also if you have a data example of the output from your laptop to show in contrast to the Raspberry output you show.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer. I'm going to try messing with the clip buffer size. If that doesn't work, I'll give your AudioCue library a try. I don't really feel like setting up a Maven project on the Pi so I'll probably download the jar and add it to the classpath the old fashioned way :)


Here are the first three lines of output when running on my laptop. The rest of the output is much the same (mostly 0ms, a couple of 1ms entries).
Pos: 0, duration: 1
Pos: 471, duration: 0
Pos: 1412, duration: 0

Comment: Adjusting the clip buffer size (either very low or very high) didn't make an appreciable difference, but AudioCue looks like a winner! Seeing consistent 0ms durations whilst getting frame position on the Pi. I think the polyphony and real-time volume features will come in handy for me too. Thanks! I'll let you know if I'm successful in integrating AudioCue into my codebase.

Comment: That's great news! I'd be grateful to hear more. Can email directly using address at the end of the AudioCue readme.